# TableView with multiple cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm calling in two separate data in my table. I can change the first call to the data, for example, I can use the switch button. But I can't use the switch button of the data I added in the second, so I can't use the didSelectRowAt property of the data. I can't use the switch button of deviceitemnew, but I can't use didSelectRowAt. So the cell in the code.buttonNew. I can't use the addTarget feature. Probably " return items."count " is a matter of concern.

Click on the button above the photo, click on the button below.

[image: Photo]

```
var items: [Device] = []
var itemsnew: [NewDevice] = []

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {    
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return items.count

    }
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell




        if newdevicechipnumber.isHidden == false {
            let deviceItemNew: NewDevice = itemsnew[indexPath.row]
            cell.new = deviceItemNew
            cell.titleNew.text = deviceItemNew.titleNew
            cell.title1New.text = deviceItemNew.placesNew
            cell.titlesaatNew.text = deviceItemNew.timeNew
            cell.buttonNew.isOn = deviceItemNew.stateNew
            cell.buttonNew.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshDataNew), for: .touchUpInside)

           return cell
        }

        let deviceItem: Device = items[indexPath.row]

        cell.badgeColor = UIColor.flatLime
        cell.badgeTextColor = .white;
        cell.badgeFontSize = 13;
        cell.badgeString = deviceItem.time
       cell.badgeOffset = CGPoint(x:70.0, y:50.0)


        cell.deviceItem = deviceItem
        cell.title.text = deviceItem.title
        cell.title1.text = deviceItem.places
        cell.titlesaat.text = deviceItem.time
        cell.button.isOn = deviceItem.state
        cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData), for: .touchUpInside)

        tablerow = String (indexPath.row)
        cell.tablerow1 = tablerow


            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.09)


        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand your question. Your problem is in touching the switch button or displaying it?.

Comment: Click on the button above the photo, click on the button below.

Comment: Do you want to add a target to both buttons in all cells?

Comment: I can't do the second switch on the button in the cell, but I can turn the first button on and off in the cell.

Comment: Try my answer below